# Advice on software design of project

Tags: c++, software-design

I plan to hook up a raspberry pi to a 64x64 led matrix, and writing a sort-of boot loader software written in c++. I would like the software to be plug-and-play with custom games I make. That is, I put all the compiled code for the games into a directory and the boot loader will recognize them and, using `fork()` and `execvp()` calls, run the selected games. I want there to be different states to the loader such as: `start_state`, `game_selection_state`, `preview_state`, `idle_state` to name a few. Each state would do their own thing and a transition from state to state based on input from a input device or idle time.

Now I do not know the best way as far as the architecture to set this up. I am not even sure that a state machine is the best way to handle this. But so far, what I have come up with is I would have 2 threads.

Thread 1:
Handles all the functionality and sanity of the states. This would include starting, stopping, and data of each state. It would also include function calls to transition from state to state.

Thread 2:
Parses input from the input Device (game controller) and makes sure a transition is valid. Then using a thread 1's function calls change the state accordingly. I planned on using a message queue to send any input that is not reserved for transitioning to the current state. (E.g A & B signify transitioning, but Y is pressed and would be sent to current state) This way the state can do what ever it wants with these button presses.

Now where this gets a little fuzzy is when the user picks a game a `fork()` call will be made inside a thread and I have read this can cause issues. If I did do it this way I would need a way to terminate or halt thread 2 until `execvp()` call ends.

Now what I want to know is this a valid or best way of implementing something like this.

Comment: How does the bootloader know which games to run and in which order?

Comment: Usually a bootloader initializes the the platform then executes an application (via function pointer).  The bootloader then disappears is not executed again.

Comment: Well I would want the loader to look at a directory and display all the different games. The user would pick one he wants to play and once the selection is made the loader would start that game. Also when the game exits it would resume execution.